# I am unable to make migrations , its showing conflicting migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-errors

I cloned *my proj* from the repository to a different computer, but after *DB restore* now there are conflicting migrations, I have looked into other answers they have mentioned about chain dependency , i am having trouble understanding how will it fix this

Below are my last 2 migration files

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0016_auto_20210817_1851'),
    ]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='placedorder',
        name='order_time',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
    ),
]





class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('orders', '0016_merge_20210828_1519'),
    ('orders', '0017_alter_placedorder_order_time'),
]

operations = [
]






Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
        res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 149, in handle
        loader.project_state(),
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 335, in project_state
        return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 315, in make_state
        project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 89, in mutate_state
        operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 162, in state_forwards
        old_field = model_state.fields.pop(self.name)
    KeyError: 'session_id'
```

**updated error:**

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0012_remove_cart_session_id, 0017_alter_placedorder_order_time in orders).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'
```

Comment: Try deleting and remaking migrations (note that rows in database can be lost)

Comment: after deleting it , now when i try to run migrations it is showing this,  `CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0012_remove_cart_session_id, 0017_alter_placedorder_order_time in orders).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'`

Comment: Run python manage.py makemigrations --merge

Comment: i tried that as well , didn't help

Comment: You have deleted all migrations files before running python manage.py makemigrations? Because in the error message are shown existing migrations files (0012 and 0017)

Comment: thanks yes, i wasn't deleting them all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RedWheelbarrow my issue was fixed by deleting all the migration files in associated app, but before doing that kindly take *DB backup*